# Force password expiry has screwed Team System 2008 - how do I fix it?

Tags: tfs

Ok, once again a forced password expiry has inadvertently screwed with our TFSSERVICE and other TFS accounts, so Team System (2008) no longer works. I've picked my way through all the steps I can think of to fix the issue, and I have one issue remaining:

Here are my steps so far:

```
On any machine on the domain change the password for domain accounts TFSSERVICE and DEVBUILDSERVER. Note the new passwords.

On the Team Foundation Server
•   Update the login password for Team Foundation Server Task Scheduler service and restart the service. (TFSSERVICE  account)
•   Update identity password for the application pool Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Tool, and restart it. (TFSSERVICE  account)
•   Execute the command "TFSADMINUTIL changepassword domain\TFSSERVICE newpassword".
•   Via a browser connect to the reporting services website (http://<TFSxx>/reports) and update the password for the TfsReportDS and the TfsOlapReportDS data sources.

On the build agent update the password for the TFSBUILD service, update the login password for the SQLEXPRESS service,  and restart both services. (DEVBUILDSERVER account).
```

However although source control and CI builds now work, when I look at a project portal I see the following:

Remaining Work

```
 Report Generated: 12/01/2015 13:34:32 by AS\neil; Last Warehouse Update: 28/10/2014 13:59:48 


 How much work is left and when will it be done? 

 No data matches the parameters specified.
```

whereas I should be seeing a graph.

What vital step have I overlooked?

TIA

Comment: Is your project portal rendering an RS report or an Excel services one?

Comment: I suggest that you upgrade TFS. 2008 is very aging and while supported has lots of niggles (like password changes) that are a lot better and Easier nore resilient in newer versions... You can still use older visual studio versions with TFS 2013...

Comment: That's not actually a solution if you have no money. "Mr Garage, my brakes need fixing." "I suggest you buy a new car, Sir". I doubt if VS2008 TFS is wearing out, so I really only need to know if someone can spot what I have missed out in the steps above.

Comment: "Is your project portal rendering an RS report or an Excel services one". I guess it is an RS report, as it worked before and the only thing that has changed is that a password change has been forced and something has not subsequently had its password reset.

Comment: Check this article it states where all the services are http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253149(v=vs.90).aspx and also this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552178(v=vs.90).aspx that state how to change the service account password.

Comment: ?? Upgrading TFS is FREE. There is no additional cost.

Comment: Only if you have an MSDN subscription for each user. If you don't, you have to BUY it!